# How to send json format input to ODATA?

Tags: json, input, odata

I are trying to consume an OData Service whose purpose is to takes search criteria and returns the search results. I m using ODataJClient java library to consume the service.

I wanted to know if the input search criteria can be passed in JSON format to the OData Service. The catch is when we use the GET request, we are limited by the character length while the POST request would actually create a new entity with the payload. Any suggestions on how can we send the JSON input ? Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate with Service with JSON format, try add the following in request headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
```

Comment: Is it applicable even for the GET request. Will it accept the JSON payload through GET request ?

Comment: @Inquisitive Why Get request contains payload? What you want to pass in payload of Get request ?

Comment: I have a json object which contains the search criteria. Something like { fn : "" , Addr : [ {home : ""}, {office : ""} ] . This json object is going to be dynamically built from the user input. So, if the user input has many fields, then its difficult for passing this payload to the GET using url rewriting ( http://mysvc.sv?fn=xyz&home=abc)